# Accessing JSON Server Hosted on a Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machine, localhost, json

I have set up a Linux Virtual Machine on my Mac (Kubuntu 14.04). On it I am running a JSON server using a Python script that is hosting it at `localhost:8080`. Is there a way I can access this from the Mac host machine? I have found stuff on doing it between Linux and Windows, but not a Mac.

I have tried going into Fusion settings and changing the network adapter setting to “Bridged Autodetect”, but it seems to still be unable to find the machine.

It seems like the VM is having a hard time getting network connectivity. I am not sure what would cause this. It was fine when I used the “Share with my Mac” option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Problem was with the bridged connection for some reason. Using NAT works fine if accessing locally from the host machine with the virtual machine's IP and the necessary port.